# Postgres how to check if user has CREATEDB permissions?

Tags: postgresql

I need to check if a specific user has permissions to create a database in Postgres. How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
select rolcreatedb
from pg_authid 
where rolname = 'your user name'
```

Comment: For the current user, use `rolname = current_user`.

Comment: Use `pg_roles` instead of `pg_authid` if you're not superuser.

Comment: What I use to  quickly check the permissions on the current role: `SELECT * FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = current_user`

Comment: yech. pg_roles is public for all. @mfcallahan

Comment: Worth noting that `rolcreatedb` can be false for super users but they can still create a database. Selecting `rolcreatedb OR rolsuper` should work better

Answer (score 1):

There are database functions that can do this for you eg: 
`has_database_privilege(user, database, privilege)`

See here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-info.html for a list of functions and here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-priv.html for the privileges to test against.

hth

Comment: I don't have a database parameter to provide to that function. I want to check if there is a permission on server level, not db level.

Comment: This may be the function you are after, then:  `pg_has_role(user, role, privilege)`  (from the same page).